# Write IMEI on unrooted Android Phone via Engineer Mode

Tags: android, mode, imei

yesterday I reset my phone to factory definitions and after it rebooted IMEI was missing (invalid IMEI). I tried to access the Engineer Mode -> GPRS to write it again, but there's no the button "Write" to add IMEI.

PS: My phone is not rooted, can you confirm me, if that's the reason I can't add the IMEI
The phone is a MTK6577 Cortex-A9 dual core

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guys, I found (3 days ago) the solution, unfortunately I can't post the video and explain how to do, because I dunno the stackoverflow rules regarding external links. 
Anyway PM me and if I read your message in time, I'll be delighted to help :)

And remember, is not even need to root your phone, therefore you won't risk you device guarantee. 

-- 
Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
First try to get the Code for the engineering mode.
example *#*#889988#*#*  or *#*#3646633#*#*
display will appear,
scroll for Menu GPRS
Press.
Screen will indicate to
write your 15 digit IMEI numbers
then Press Write IMEI.
Then reboot your phone.
check IMEI using *#06#
Good luck, hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Now solve your `Invalid IMEI` problem easily with no risk

1. Dial `*#*#3646633#*#*`
2. Then Goto `Connectivity` and select `CDS Information`
3. In That Select `Radio Information` and select `phone 1`
4. For `Sim 1` Type `AT+EGMR=1,7,"Your IMEI Number"` and press `SEND AT COMMAND`
5. For `Sim 2` Type `AT+EGMR=1,10,"Your IMEI Number"` and press `SEND AT COMMAND`
6. It will show that `AT Command sent or command sent`
7. **Reboot** Your Device and Problem Solved......!!!!!!!
8. Enjoy.......!!!!!!!!!!